# Transparent NavigationBar in Matplotlib (or, can the Navigation buttonsbe added without a bar?)

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt, qt5, toolbar, matplotlib-widget

I'm trying to maximise use of space in a Qt GUI with an embedded matplotlib figure, including the standard matplotlib navigation bar to provide useful functionality for the user (zoom, save, move etc.)

Unfortunately, the NavigationBar ends up taking up a a lot of space when the plot window has a 'widescreen' ratio, as seen below. All of the buttons are on the left hand side, but the NavigationBar creates a whole bar of white space as well.
[image]

While my intended application is embedding a matplotlib figure in a Qt GUI, I believe this is a general question that could also apply to the standard figure displayed by the default matplotlib ax.plot operation.

Is it possible to use this space? I tried setting text and mpl widgets here, but they are always hidden behind the navigation bar. Perhaps there is a setting to make the colour of this bar transparent?

Alternatively, is there a quick way to add in the buttons as widgets on to my figure, so the NavigationBar is not needed. I like the style and functionality offered by the bar, so would rather not have to manually re-implement each one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NavigationToolbar` is a normal `QWidget`. This means that you can do everything with it that you would also be able to do with other widgets, including

- placing it into layouts of other widgets
- putting it into menus
- changing it's layout
- position it absolutely inside the GUI
- etc...

The question is a bit too broad to provide solutions for all of those; but there are also enough resources available on how to manipulate and position widgets in PyQt.

Below is an example for an absolutely positionned `NavigationToolbar`, which is (by default) transparent. The toolbar is positionned at the origin of the axes and will stay there if the figure is resized.

[image: GUI with tranparent navigation toolbar]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, fig):
        self.qapp = QtGui.QApplication([])

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.widget.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        self.widget.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.widget.layout().setSpacing(0)

        self.fig = fig
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.mpl_connect("resize_event", self.resize)

        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.nav = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.widget, coordinates=False)
        self.nav.setMinimumWidth(300)
        self.nav.setStyleSheet("QToolBar { border: 0px }")

        self.show()
        self.qapp.exec_()

    def resize(self, event):
        # on resize reposition the navigation toolbar to (0,0) of the axes.
        x,y = self.fig.axes[0].transAxes.transform((0,0))
        figw, figh = self.fig.get_size_inches()
        ynew = figh*self.fig.dpi-y - self.nav.frameGeometry().height()
        self.nav.move(x,ynew)

# create a figure with a subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3))
# colorize figure and axes to make transparency obvious
fig.set_facecolor("#e9c9ef") 
ax.set_facecolor("#f7ecf9")
ax.plot([2,3,5,1], color="#ab39c1")
fig.tight_layout()

# pass the figure to the custom window
a = Window(fig)
```

Comment: Thanks - this works well to position the NavBar in the GUI somewhere more compact. As a point of interest, is it possible to overlay this (i.e. Qt Widgets generally) over the top of other layers, ideally including some transparency too?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and if it doesn't work, update your question with a [mcve] and a clear problem description?

Comment: I had a closer look at this and provided a complete example in the updated answer.

Comment: I was trying to achieve this but it didn't work nearly as well as that code example. Thanks so much for this!